# Relação entre performance e escalabilidade

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, desempenho, escalabilidade

Eu estava enfrentando problemas para realizar a manutenção em um código de minha autoria, por conta das classes extensas e pouco definidas (cresceu muito com o tempo), para simplificar a questão vou dividir a linha temporal do código em versão 1 e 2.

**Versão 1:**

Praticamente toda a construção das telas e inicialização das variáveis ocorria no método main, embora tivessemos uma quantidade relativamente grande de classes externas (Componentes, entidades etc) e as classes relacionadas com o banco de dados eram divididas em Select, Delete, Update e Insert.

Como relatado acima a principal dificuldade aqui era a manutenção, embora não fosse tão difícil achar os métodos acabou ficando muito código sem uso com o tempo e a propagação de erros era difícil de lidar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Versão 2:**

Quase que a totalidade do código foi redistribuída, [dividindo os pacotes por funcionalidade](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) e quebrando o código em classes menores com propósito mais definido.

De imediato a manutenção do código ficou muito mais fácil além de permitir que eu extenda funcionalidades com quase zero propagação de erros. Todavia a performance da aplicação caiu visivelmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Durante a universidade, acredito que por conta de produzirmos projetos pequenos e de uso pessoal, não temos que nos preocupar muito com a relação entre performance e escalabilidade.

Minha dúvida é se, "no mundo real", essas duas métricas são **inconciliáveis**, de forma que investindo em uma **necessariamente** teremos que abrir mão da outra?

Obs.: Para os puristas, adotemos como métrica para performance o tempo de resposta da aplicação.

Comment: Quando o assunto é a organização do código, nunca vi perda do desempenho ser discutida. A suspeita recai sobre algum trecho de código ou erro de programação que esteja causando isso. Seria o caso de investigar, procurando ferramentas que ajudem nesse processo de investigação.

Comment: Também tenho essa suspeita, mas aproveitei a situação para verificar se na prática temos que realmente balancear performance e escalabilidade.